# rails does not recognize mysql2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I'm unable to have rails recognize the mysql2 gem that I've installed. I'm using rails 3.1 and ruby 1.9.2. I'm stumped here..

```
dan@luci:~$ cd snorby/
Using: /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby

dan@luci:~/snorby$ gem list -l | grep mysql2
mysql2 (0.3.11)

dan@luci:~/snorby$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.0)
1.9.2p290 :001 > require 'mysql2'
LoadError: no such file to load -- mysql2
        from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
        from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
        from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
        from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
        from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
        from (irb):1
        from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
        from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

dan@luci:~/snorby$ echo $GEM_PATH
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby:/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global

dan@luci:~/snorby$ ls -l /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 2 dan dan  4096 2012-08-17 14:22 benchmark
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan 12460 2012-08-17 14:22 CHANGELOG.md
drwxr-xr-x 2 dan dan  4096 2012-08-17 14:22 examples
drwxr-xr-x 3 dan dan  4096 2012-08-17 14:22 ext
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan    25 2012-08-17 14:22 Gemfile
drwxr-xr-x 3 dan dan  4096 2012-08-17 14:22 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan  1090 2012-08-17 14:22 MIT-LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan  1099 2012-08-17 14:22 mysql2.gemspec
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan    99 2012-08-17 14:22 Rakefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan 11978 2012-08-17 14:22 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 4 dan dan  4096 2012-08-17 14:22 spec
drwxr-xr-x 2 dan dan  4096 2012-08-17 14:22 tasks

dan@luci:~/snorby$ rvm info

ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux luci 2.6.32-37-powerpc #81-Ubuntu Fri Dec 2 21:46:08 UTC 2011 ppc GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.10.0 by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"
    updated:      "7 months 10 days 23 hours 13 minutes 10 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p290"
    date:         "2011-07-09"
    platform:     "powerpc-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2011-07-09 revision 32553"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [powerpc-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby"
    ruby:         "/home/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby/bin:/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/home/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/dan/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@snorby:/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290"
    IRBRC:        "/home/dan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "snorby"

dan@luci:~/snorby$ bundle exec gem list -l | grep mysql2

dan@luci:~/snorby$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to require it manually? Bundler should take care of that.

Comment: check `bundle exec gem list -l | grep mysql2`

Comment: well, I made a rake task that needs the mysql2 gem. I manually installed the mysql2 gem with 'gem install mysql2'; however, I did not put it in the Gemfile. I'll try that now.

Comment: mpapis: just tried that and put the output in an edit

Comment: Did you bundle after adding it to the gem file? Bundler can't see it according to what you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails will automatically use `Bundler.setup` when starting, it is equivalent with `bundle exec` from command line, to allow loading **mysql** gem you need it to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`, best if you place it in proper group - some projects use **pg** for production and **mysql** for development, if you plan always using it then it can be specified without group.

Comment: thanks for the answer. so does Rails not look for local gems installed when Bundler is in use?

Comment: it's bundler limiting the list of available gems, you would need to load a gem before initializing bundler, but then if a other version of the same gem is available via bundler then it would conflict with the one already loaded